# How to convert void* to foo* to comply with C++?

Tags: c++, c, qt, gcc

I am trying to compile a code written in C (ndpiReader.c program that comes with nDPI library, hosted [here](https://svn.ntop.org/svn/ntop/trunk/nDPI/example/ndpiReader.c)). I'm using Qt Creator and GCC compiler.

After doing some research [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8843818/what-does-the-fpermissive-flag-do) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19214645/how-to-suppress-warnings-for-void-to-foo-conversions-reduced-from-errors), I notice that compiling C code with C++ compiler is not the best idea. But I didn't get the answer of how to do this conversion and make this code C++ compatible.

When I try to run the code in Qt Creator I get the error bellow:

> error: invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'ndpi_flow_struct*' [-fpermissive]
>          if((newflow->ndpi_flow = malloc_wrapper(size_flow_struct)) == NULL) {
>                                                                  ^

If more info is needed to solve the problem please leave a comment. I'm new to C++ so detailed answers with links are so much appreciated.

Edit: here is `malloc_wrapper()` function's code

```
static void *malloc_wrapper(unsigned long size) {
  current_ndpi_memory += size;

  if(current_ndpi_memory > max_ndpi_memory)
    max_ndpi_memory = current_ndpi_memory;

  return malloc(size);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're seeing this error because in `c++`, types should have an exact match.

As we can see, the `malloc_wrapper()` function returns a `void *` and your `newflow->ndpi_flow` is of type `ndpi_flow_struct*`. So while compiling using `c++` compiler, you've to add the `cast`, like

```
if((newflow->ndpi_flow=(ndpi_flow_struct*)malloc_wrapper(size_flow_struct)) == NULL) { . . .
```

to force the compiler in believing that the return value of `malloc_wrapper()` is of type `(ndpi_flow_struct*)`.

or even better, the `static cast<>` (keeping in mind the `C++` aspect), like

```
if(( newflow->ndpi_flow = 
                static_cast<ndpi_flow_struct*>malloc_wrapper(size_flow_struct)) == NULL) { . . .
```

Related Reading: [A detailed answer on C++ Casting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/332030/2173917).

Comment: I think the (equivalent) static_cast<> is more appropriate and more c++

Comment: @Elemental Well, I'm not an expert in `c++`, thanks for the suggestion. Can you please review to make sure the edit looks ok?

Comment: @Nobody - keep in mind C++ won't allow certain `static_cast`s which will otherwise work just fine with the less verbose good old C style cast.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, we just write

```
if((newflow->ndpi_flow = (ndpi_flow_struct*)malloc_wrapper(size_flow_struct)) == NULL) {
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, it works fine, I accepted Sourav's answer because it was more detailed.

Comment: c-style casts are discouraged. The accepted way to do this is to use the least permissive of static_cast, reinterpret_cast and const_cast that will get the conversion done.

Comment: @RichardHodges C-style casts are discouraged _in C++_. However, the question is about compiling C code (with a C++ compiler). To maintain compilability in C, it would be necessary to use a C-style cast.